# Will Ubuntu format my whole HDD if I let it install automatically

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu so please bear with me.

So I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my old laptop. I chose the "something else" button and there was a problem with booting that `boot-repair` could not fix so I decided to let it install on its own this time.

I have got my main partition I use for files and its size is around 350 GB, another partition of the size of 50GB and a third one which is 100GB. However, I want to keep the files on the 350GB partition. I'm scared that if I let it install automatically it will format my HDD, and if I install as "something else" it wont boot (yes I created a 200MB EFI partition).

My question is, will Ubuntu really format the whole HDD? What options do I have?

Note: I don't have Windows on my PC.

Comment: "*a problem with booting that boot-repair could not fix*" is too vague to offer real advice. "Something Else" worked properly when I used it two days ago.

Answer (score 0):

You have an option:
Boot using Linux Live USB, open `gparted` create partitions which you need and then finally install Ubuntu on those partitions.

Comment: Yeah, already did that. I wanted to install it on the 50GB partition but it wont boot.

Comment: Open your BIOS and select the preferred OS to boot as first priority.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it will. It creates a drive as whole one. So, Create a separate partition to install ubuntu in your HDD.So, Creating portion just see any video on Youtube it will help you.